# cmake and how to avoid unzip an archive multiple times

Tags: cmake, tar, unzip

I am using the following cmake command to extract a zip file

```
 ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar xkf
```

This unzip the file as it is.

I'd like to AVOID unzipping when the file has been already unzipped.
How can I do that? It seems that there is no option for that purpose.

Comment: Test for a file or a directory that comes from the archive. If it exists, skip your `tar` command.

Answer (score 0):

Add an dependency.

The result of the unzip operation has to be used within a later build step. Add the dependency between the unzip and that build step.

1. Use `add_custom_command` to unzip files and copy them to the expected folder
2. Extend your target by a dependency to the extracted files

The following example shows this for the target `TTNLIB`.

Example:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ttnbitvector.cpp
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar xkf ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/ttnbitvector.cpp.zip -C ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/ttnbitvector.cpp ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ttnbitvector.cpp
WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external
COMMENT Extract ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ttnbitvector.cpp
)

add_library(TTNLIB SHARED ${SOURCES} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ttnbitvector.cpp)
```

Note: Read the documentation of [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/add_custom_command.html)

See [cmake solutions](http://www.th-thielemann.de/cmake) for further information.